# Training a face recognition model takes longer than expected

Tags: machine-learning

I am doing a small project with the basic idea of recognizing a face. I made a version that uses `face_recognition` library. And, although I am quite satisfied with the results I am not happy with the time it takes for the program to finish. I am quite sure that this is due to `face_recognition` does not use GPU/CUDA despite me having GPU on my machine. in particular the function

```
face_recognition.face_locations(picture, model="cnn")
```

does all the computation on CPU. In the docs of this function it says that it will use CPU if it cannot use GPU. However, I used GPU with another library and it was fine. I would be happy for any help that you can give me.

P.S. Probably you know other libraries that I probably should pay attention to.

Edit: [the link to the face_recognition library](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition).

Comment: This seems like a problem with configuring and using a specific library. Please identify the library, your GPU and also the library that you successfully used GPU acceleration with on the same machine.

Comment: The library that is supposed to use GPU is face_recognition. it's version is 1.2.3. Also face_recognition uses dlib. It's version is 19.8.1. I tried to install newer version of dlib from pip, but I get some errors. I searched through numerous of forums and couldn't find the answer, probably because I am using Windows 10. The library that I used GPU successfully is fastai. It is built on top of pytorch. My GPU is NVIDIA 960X. Cuda 8.0

Comment: I expect quite a few libraries are called "face_recognition". Could you please link it in the question - use [edit].

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I also see on a quick search that dlib has some things you need to do before it will use GPU at all - e.g. https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/issues/303 implies you need to compile it differently - I hope someone who knows dlib with Windows better can help further.

Comment: Thank you. I have seen this thread, I thought that finding Linux machine would solve my problem. So I tried my code in Google Colab. I assume it uses Linux under hood. However, after installing all the libraries there and running my code, it still said that it uses CPU.

Comment: Now I am thinking of doing face recognition with pytorch. Though not sure where to start.